# C++ PugiXML Vector Iterators Incompatible Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, box2d, sfml, pugixml

I have an application where I parse XML code into sprites with textures using PugiXML. However, I'm experiencing problems getting this one `for` loop working, as the compiler keeps returning the `Expression: vector iterators incompatible` run-time error during the loop, right when `initCollisionObject` is  initiated. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

`for` Loop:

```
for (xml_node collisions = doc.child("level").child("collisions").child("object"); collisions; collisions = collisions.next_sibling("object"))
{
    xml_attribute textureAttribute = collisions.attribute("spritesheet");
    xml_attribute xPosAttribute = collisions.attribute("x");
    xml_attribute yPosAttribute = collisions.attribute("y");
    xml_attribute rotationAttribute = collisions.attribute("rotation");

    std::string texture = textureAttribute.as_string();
    int xPos = xPosAttribute.as_int();
    int yPos = yPosAttribute.as_int();
    int rotation = rotationAttribute.as_int();

    collisionArray.push_back(collisionObject);
    collisionArray[currentCollisionObjectIndex].initCollisionObject(texture, _world, xPos, yPos, rotation);

    currentCollisionObjectIndex++;
}
```

`initCollisionObject` Function:

```
void CollisionObject::initCollisionObject(std::string fileName, b2World &_world, float objectX, float objectY, float objectRotation)
{
    collisionObjectSpriteImage.loadFromFile(fileName);
    //spriteImage.createMaskFromColor(sf::Color::White);
    collisionObjectSpriteTexture.loadFromImage(collisionObjectSpriteImage);
    collisionObjectSprite.setTexture(collisionObjectSpriteTexture);
    width = collisionObjectSprite.getGlobalBounds().width;
    height = collisionObjectSprite.getGlobalBounds().height;
    x = objectX;
    y = objectY;
    rotation = objectRotation;
    collisionObjectSprite.setOrigin(collisionObjectSprite.getGlobalBounds().width / 2, collisionObjectSprite.getGlobalBounds().height / 2);
    collisionObjectSprite.setPosition(x, y);
    collisionObjectSprite.setRotation(rotation);

    createStaticCollision(_world, x, y, width, height, rotation);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to sound ridiculous, but restarting the computer actually solved the problem...